# How to cancel this annoying prompt? I tried many methods, but they didn't work

Tags: windows, powershell

When I open windows power shell, the following prompt will appear：

```
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Try the new cross-platform PowerShell https://aka.ms/pscore6

Cannot load PSReadline module.  Console is running without PSReadline.
```

Comment: Which methods did you try, and how did those fail? Did you get any error messages? [Edit] that info into the question, do not answer as a comment.

Comment: I seem to have found a solution, according to the article I do a good job[enter link description here][1]


  [1]: https://patrickbutlermonterde.com/2017/12/20/how-to-solve-the-cannot-load-psreadline-module-error-when-installing-the-azure-cli/

Comment: It's a setting in your profile (VSCode - user settings or ISE) or PowerShell startup shortcut. `powershell /?`

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is running powershell.exe process with `-NoLogo` switch :)

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19042.928]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

c:\>powershell.exe
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Try the new cross-platform PowerShell https://aka.ms/pscore6

PS C:\> exit

c:\>powershell.exe -NoLogo
PS C:\> exit
```

More about it here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe?view=powershell-5.1

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have found a solution, according to the article I do a good job[enter link description here](https://patrickbutlermonterde.com/2017/12/20/how-to-solve-the-cannot-load-psreadline-module-error-when-installing-the-azure-cli/)